Excel Latest Date Summary
I've got a table with dates going down and players going across, like this:

How can I write a formula for another table with names going down, and a Latest Date column based on if the table above is filled in for that date for that player?  For example Player 1 has something filled in for both dates and so it'll just be the max date, whereas Player B only had 1 date filled in, so his max date is different.


Perhaps you could try something along the lines of:


• Formula used in cell F2 (Ensure to fill down and change the ranges accordingly per your data.)
=MAX((FILTER(B$2:C$3,B$1:C$1=E2)<>"")*A$2:A$3)


• Also, can spill the output with one single array formula like as below using a LAMBDA() helper function MAP():
=MAP(E2:E3,LAMBDA(x,MAX((FILTER(B2:C3,B1:C1=x)<>"")*A2:A3)))


• And using MAXIFS() with dynamic approach:
=MAXIFS(A:A,INDEX(B:C,,XMATCH(E2,B$1:C$1)),"<>")



I guess MAXIFS would work. Something like this:
=MAXIFS($A$2:$A$100, B2:B100, "<>")

Things to note:

It would copy horizontally not vertically, so you'd need to adjust the range of B2:B100 as needed.
Checking for blank was not intuitive but "<>" seems to mean "not blank". I guess it means "not equal to nothing" being just a not equal sign by itself.


Another option could be =MAX(A$2:A$3*(B$2:C$3>"")*(B$1:C$1=D2))
Or dynamic including all players:
=LET(x,LAMBDA(y,TOCOL(IFS(B2:C3>"",y),2)),GROUPBY(x(B1:C1),x(A2:A3),MAX,,0))
Or using 1 input range including headers:
=LET(a,A1:C3,b,LAMBDA(c,TOCOL(IFS(DROP(a,1,1)>"",c),2)),GROUPBY(b(DROP(TAKE(a,1),,1)),b(DROP(TAKE(a,,1),1)),MAX,,0))
